# List all posts without at least one category assigned to them in admin

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to allow the admin user to list out CPT that have not already had a category assigned to them (This is to enable them to quickly find posts that require a category and edit them)

I have this so far -

```
function function_name( $query ) {
  global $post_type;
  if ( is_admin() && $post_type == 'product' ) {
    $query->set( 'cat', '' );
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'function_name' );
```

This does not work however. Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved what I need this way, if anyone else comes up with this question -

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
   'taxonomy' => 'category',
   'hide_empty' => false,
) );

$arr = array();

foreach ($terms as $term) {
   $arr[] = '-'.$term->term_id;
}

$query->set( 'cat', $arr );
```

I am simply getting all category id's. looping through these and appending them to another array with a munis "-" value and passing them through to the query as an argument.